# I only don't understand one line in this given proof regarding a sequence becoming constant modulo n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

As shown in image below, I understand Euler's Totient Function and all that except that one line marked in "red" namely, how does the inductive hypothesis prove that congruence involving Euler's totient function? Any clarification is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

[image: Euler Totient Function How?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is strong induction on $n$. The author is saying:

Assume by strong induction that

$$x_{k}\equiv x_{k+1}\ (\text{mod }m)$$

for all $k\geq m$ and all $m<n$. The author is doing induction on $n$, not $k$. They then simply note that

$$\phi(b)\leq b-1\leq n-1<n$$

and thus satisfies the strong induction assumption that.

Comment: Yea I was thinking induction on k not n. I think I understand it now. Thank you so much :)